# Do "owed" and "due" mean the opposite?

Tags: meaning

I wonder if "owed" and "due" mean the opposite in the following quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_%28accounting%29)?

> In banking and accountancy, the outstanding balance is the amount of
> money **owed**, (or **due**), that remains in a deposit account (or a
> loan account) at a given date, after all past remittances, payments
> and withdrawal have been accounted for. It can be positive (then, in
> the balance sheet of a firm, it is an asset) or negative (a
> liability).

I think  owed and due both mean someone owes someone else another something. But in the quote, it looks like owed means someone else owes someone something, and due means someone owes someone else something. I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this question! It helped me a lot. I could not understand what "due" means in amounts due. Now, I know even more that there is amount owed as well as amount due.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Owed** and **due** are closely related.

**Owed**, without more explanation, means the *total amount of debt obligated to be paid by A to B*

**Due** means the *amount of debt that is expected to be paid by a given date (a **due date**) from A to B*.

At times they are the same, at times **due** is a subset of **owed**. This assumes that the person owing is also the person from whom payment is due. In legal jargon, they are often used together in the phrase *due and owing*.

Comment: Thanks! In the quote "the amount of money owed, (or due), that remains in a deposit account (or a loan account) at a given date", If I understand correctly, deposit account shows the money a customer lend to the bank, and load account shows the money the bank lend to the customer. So don't owed and due mean the opposite?

Comment: Thanks! Can you relate to deposit and loan accounts?

Comment: Deposit and loan accounts both represent available funds, but are fundamentally different, and *owed* and *due* can mean different things depending on context. If I receive periodic advances from a bank, an amount is *due* from the bank, it is an obligation on them, but ultimately is becomes my debt. Now we are getting into legal and business analysis rather than language.

Comment: See also the general theory of the [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

"Owed" and "due" can apply in either direction: You may owe the bank money or they may owe you money. In your example, I think they are just indicating that "due" here is a synonym for "owed", though broader context may indicate a more specific meaning is intended.

As Bib indicates, "amount due" is the amount that someone is obligated to pay as of a specific date, which may or may not be the total obligation.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia quote does not state "due" is opposed to "owed", but pertains to mean that *owed* and *due* are interchangeable. We all know the amount due to the merchant, is the amount owed by the customer. The amount owed, is therefore the amount owed by a merchant to a customer.